# How to specify parameter type in R2DBC when using stored procedures?

Tags: java, spring, plsql, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

For example, in JDBC we specify `typeName` the following way:

```
String procedure = "{? = call CREATE_A_PERSON (?)}";
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(procedure);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.STRUCT, "UDO_PERSON");
statement.setString(2, "YOURE NAME");
statement.execute();
```

As mentioned [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286769/how-do-i-call-by-jdbc-a-pl-sql-function-that-returns-an-udo-and-interpret-that-r/8293991#8293991).

In R2DBC, the same can be done using `Parameters.in` or `Parameters.out`. But for objects like arrays or structures, I've not been able to find any way to pass the `typeName` (`UDO_PERSON` in above) to the connection statement. How do I do that?

```
Parameters.out(R2dbcType.COLLECTION,"UDO_PERSON")
```

The above throws a "cannot resolve method" error.

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure declaration ?